# Posting emoticon from iOS to Facebook via WebAPI

Tags: c#, ios, facebook, asp.net-web-api, emoticons

I am facing a problem that I cannot seem to overcome.

**Context**

I have an iOS application running on iOS7.0 and greater. In this application, you have the possibility to post pictures with comments. These pictures and comments are then sent to a .NET C# MVC WebAPI, which itself sends the content to Facebook using the Facebook SDK.

**Problem**

When I post comments with emoticons on the iOS app, I am able to successfully store the comments in the database through the Web API and to retrieve them. It shows properly as emoticons on the iOS app. However, once the comment is sent to Facebook, it shows the actual text stored in the database (normal, I guess).

**I would like however to have Facebook display the emoticon I am sending from the emoji keyboard on iOS.**

> Comments with emoticon !! \ud83d\ude04\ud83d\ude0d

**Additional Information**

On iOS, I take the string containing the comment, I first encode it using UTF8 and I return a new string using NonLossyASCII.

To display it on iOS, I take the string shown above and I do the opposite; I encode it using NonLossyASCII and return a new string using UTF8.

Any hint or help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried UTF-16?

Comment: What is your solution? I am facing the similar problem.